Does TIBCO Scribe Online REST Connector now support OpenAPI 3.0?
I'm trying to create a connector in TIBCO Scribe with a REST API that uses OpenAPI Specification 3.0. While no errors appear as I paste the specification into the specification box, I'm unable to run the test connection or save the configuration.
I found this TIBCO support article, which says that the REST connector only supports OpenAPI 2.0, and that 3.0 isn't compatible. Since this article is three years old, I'd like to know if there has been an update to the connector that allows it to work with OpenAPI 3.0.
